# convention of writing nth root of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, notation, soft-question

I wonder if there is a concrete reason for using factors of $\mathrm{1 \ , \ ω \ , \ ... \ , \ ω^{n-1}}$ to express the $\mathrm{n^{th}}$ roots of unity (besides just convenience)? That is opposed to using exponential notation.

Comment: There are roots of unity in other rings than $\mathbb C$, too. And those can't be written using exponentials.

Comment: @SZL Ultimately, any choice of notation is "just convenience"

Comment: @SZL One common "trick" that becomes more obvious when writing roots as the powers of $\omega$ is to write a sum of roots as a geometric series.

Comment: If nothing else, $\,\omega^k\,$ is a lot more compact than $\,e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}\,$.